# Schengen Visa Extension Possibilites

Tags: schengen

I have a 7 day Schengen Validity Visa and currently visiting one of the Schengen countries. Is it possible to have a few days extension in the visa? or can i stay up to my Visa Validity Date?

Also, is it ok to apply for another Schengen Validity Visa after i leave the Schengen zone.

Comment: What is a "Schengen Validity Visa", as opposed to just a normal Schengen visa?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I suspect that a "7 day Schengen Validity Visa" is a normal Schengen visa that is valid for a seven-day duration of stay.